# Can I have a file with the same name in 2 folders inside iphone's document directory?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsdocument

I checked and understood that we can create folders by different name inside documents directory.

My doubt is I have created two folders, folder1 and folder2. Is it possible to have a file named rock.pdf inside each the directories? Both the files will be different but will be having same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. The same file name in different folders is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when designers handed to me **png** resources for an app. AFAIK you can. However you will get a compiler warning stating that you have two entries for the same file name. I don't know what the side effects are, because I hate warnings and I corrected that in a second.

Comment: That's a different thing, you are talking about two files with the same name in the resource bundle.

Comment: ya, this is not what i meant. I was asking about downloading two files of same name to two folders in document directory programmatically.